# Solr query SolrInputDocument via http request

Tags: node.js, solr

I got into a very specific issue, I cannot find an answer so I decided to come here.

I have a Node.js application where I am storing an array via Solr. (using solr-client solrClient.add method)

I have the following object here that I get after running a /select request for an id. (id:2449t534-dvvf-3636-a4d9-12312412412/data#0/data#0)

```
"paths": [
                "[SolrInputDocument(fields: [something_id=1, name=test1, type=stuff1, createdAt=2023-07-12T19:03:26.291Z, updatedAt=2023-07-12T19:03:26.291Z, paths=[SolrInputDocument(fields: [something_id=2, name=test2, type=stuff2, createdAt=2023-07-12T19:03:26.291Z, updatedAt=2023-07-12T19:03:26.291Z])]])]"
            ],
```

I want to be able to query the paths inside this array but I don't understand how, I tried Block Join Query Parser but that only returned empty objects so I need a way to query something_id=1 for example.

I tried Block Join Query Parser but it doesn't seem to work (nor the parent method or the child one)

Comment: Can you clarify what's stored in Solr? Aren't you just looking for a "filter query" `fq=something_id:1`?

Comment: Yes, in Solr I am storing an array, let's say it looks like this
`[
{
  type='file',
  name="something"
  paths: [
    {
    something_id: 1,
    name: test1
    type=stuff1
    paths: [
    {
       name=test2
       type=stuff2
     }
     ]
    }
  ]
},
]`

Comment: .fq({field: 'path_id', value: '1'}) will return empty object

Comment: According to this it seems like you've stored the text `[SolrInputDocument(fields: .."` inside a multivalued field in Solr - i.e. what has been stored is a stringified representation of a SolrInputDocument?

Comment: Yes, I have this paths array that was saved automatically as SolrInputDocument

Comment: You can't query that in the way you intend to - it's just a raw string and it's not being handled as structured data in any way.

Comment: Yup, thanks Mats, I found what happened really... I was storying an array containing an array containing objects, that was the issue, removed that and now everything works as expected

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake, I was storing an array that was containing another array with objects instead of just one array containing objects. Changed that and now everything works perfectly, if I just stopped yesterday and took a pause I would've seen that and fix it but we all make mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

```
class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    [{
      type='file',
      name="something",
      paths: [{
        something_id: 1,
        name: test1,=stuff1,
        paths: [{
          name=test2,
          type=stuff2
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

And JavaScript Code:-

```js
console.fq({ field: 'path_id', value: '1' })
```

Comment: And JavaScript Code :-                                                                                                                                 console.fq({field: 'path_id', value: '1'})

Comment: console.fq? you probably meant to say solrClient.fq or something like that, but I found what was the issue (I was storing an array with an array with objects instead of just an array with objects), thanks!